# while loop used for reading .csv file only reading first line

Tags: c++, vector, while-loop

The following code should read my `test.csv` file. Yet the only output is 3.9.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<double> xnew2;
std::vector<double> ynew2;
double b0, b1;

void read_train() {
std::ifstream read("test.csv");
if (read.is_open()) {
    std::string line;
    while (getline(read, line)) {
        double x;
        x = std::stod(line.c_str());
        xnew2.push_back(x);
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < xnew2.size(); i++) {
    ynew2.push_back(b0 + b1 * xnew2[i]);
}
read.close();
```

}

This is the `.csv` file:

```
3.9
37.3
0
14.1
8
16.3
29.1
16.1
18.3
0
16.2
10.4
40.9
32.8
6.2
42.7
16.9
32.6
21.2
37.1
13.1
14.7
12.7
26.8
7.6
12.7
30.9
16.4
23
1.9
5.2
18.5
13.7
5.6
18.8
8.1
6.5
```

Comment: This question doesn't seem to fit the [readfile] tag scope.

Comment: Possibly you need to check the `ifstream::good()` method's specification?

Comment: Not a lot of commas in your **c**omma-**s**eparated **v**alues (CSV) file...

Comment: Next debugging steps: Look at the value of `line` after each read. Look at the value of `xnew2.size()` just before the loop that adds values to `ynew2`. Eliminate the unused variable `test`. Narrow down the problem even further than you have so far. Make your [mre] so simple that your bug has no red herrings to hide behind.

Comment: Works on my PC. No problem. But: Do never use `while (read.good())`. You will find many many similar statements here on SO. The correct solution would be to put the `getline` in the `while` statement

Comment: I fixed it using while( getline()). My function still does not work as intended and is only reads the first line